# Angular: strictTemplates and Virtual ScrollViewPort

Tags: angular, angular-material

I follow the [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58912143/325868) for Material table in a VirtualScrollViewport. The code works quite well. In one of my HTML files I have something like

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport tvsItemSize [ngStyle]=...
```

My problem now starts when I turn on the `strictTemplates` option. I get the following strange error:

```
....   error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
4   <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport tvsItemSize [ngStyle]="{'height': 'calc(
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The error message doesn't seem to make sense. The `tvsItemSize` is `TableItemSizeDirective`.  When I click to open it I get to the `rowHeight`. Anybody an idea how to fix it?